# How to detect wrong characters codification in mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have a UTF-8 database with some imported data. Some of the data that has been wrong imported, with wrong charactes, i.e. instead of Nürburgring => NÃ¼rburgring

It looks like I'm going to correct these rows by hand... so is there anyway to look for these with a select?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the connection to your db as utf8:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'someuser', 'xxx');
mysql_select_db('mydb', $connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES_junk 'utf8'", $connection);

-- get utf-8 thing
$query = sprintf('SELECT yourname FROM table where <something> = <something>');
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing mysql through sql yog then

```
Got to the database
       right click on database which you are accessing 
          alter database 
             select 'utf8' as database charset and 'utf8_general_ci' as
                 database collection
```

**EDIT :** 
try this,

```
SELECT col1 FROM  table
WHERE col1 LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```

Hope its helpfull

Comment: Hi, the problem is not the encoding of my database. My database its already in utf8. The problem was when importing data into it the INSERTS were done in latin1 (or something) so the codification is wrong.

Comment: @petekaner I have answered that if you are inserting the data for first time in a DB but that's not the answer for your question and i have edited my answer as i found after i google out